# VIEW - INDEX SQL SERVEr

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, view

Does anyone know another way to run the query below more efficiently? I'm using SQL Server 2014. I'm facing a problem if i create index on table or on view .

On table 2  (TB_FATURA_ITEM_TRANSACAO_HST) , has stored 50 million rows .

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW vItemFatura  (ID , ID_TRANSACAO , ID_FATURA ,ID_FATURA_ITEM ,ID_TIPO_SERVICO , ID_SERVICO  ,ID_TARIFA ,DATA_REGISTRO_TRANSACAO ,DATA_PAGAMENTO ,CODIGO_REFERENCIA , DESCRICAO ,MERCHANT_ID,ORDER_ID,IDENTIFICACAO_TITULO,CNPJ,NUMERO_AGENCIA,NUMERO_CONTA,QUANTIDADE_ITENS,VALOR_ITEM,VALOR_TRANSACAO,STATUS_TRANSACAO,DATA_INI_CONTABILIZACAO,DATA_FIM_CONTABILIZACAO,DATA_INI_RETROATIVO,DATA_FIM_RETROATIVO,ATIVO,DATA_INSERT,DATA_UPDATE,APP_INSERT,APP_UPDATE,VALOR_PEDIDO_EC)
AS  
SELECT 
      T1.ID
     ,T1.ID_TRANSACAO
     ,T1.ID_FATURA
     ,T1.ID_FATURA_ITEM
     ,T1.ID_TIPO_SERVICO
     ,T1.ID_SERVICO
     ,T1.ID_TARIFA
     ,T1.DATA_REGISTRO_TRANSACAO
     ,T1.DATA_PAGAMENTO
     ,T1.CODIGO_REFERENCIA
     ,T1.DESCRICAO
     ,T1.MERCHANT_ID
     ,T1.ORDER_ID
     ,T1.IDENTIFICACAO_TITULO
     ,T1.CNPJ
     ,T1.NUMERO_AGENCIA
     ,T1.NUMERO_CONTA
     ,T1.QUANTIDADE_ITENS
     ,T1.VALOR_ITEM
     ,T1.VALOR_TRANSACAO
     ,T1.STATUS_TRANSACAO
     ,T1.DATA_INI_CONTABILIZACAO
     ,T1.DATA_FIM_CONTABILIZACAO
     ,T1.DATA_INI_RETROATIVO
     ,T1.DATA_FIM_RETROATIVO
     ,T1.ATIVO
     ,T1.DATA_INSERT
     ,T1.DATA_UPDATE
     ,T1.APP_INSERT
     ,T1.APP_UPDATE
     ,T1.VALOR_PEDIDO_EC   
FROM dbo.TB_FATURA_ITEM_TRANSACAO  T1
UNION 
SELECT  
      T2.ID
     ,T2.ID_TRANSACAO
     ,T2.ID_FATURA
     ,T2.ID_FATURA_ITEM
     ,T2.ID_TIPO_SERVICO
     ,T2.ID_SERVICO
     ,T2.ID_TARIFA
     ,T2.DATA_REGISTRO_TRANSACAO
     ,T2.DATA_PAGAMENTO
     ,T2.CODIGO_REFERENCIA
     ,T2.DESCRICAO
     ,T2.MERCHANT_ID
     ,T2.ORDER_ID
     ,T2.IDENTIFICACAO_TITULO
     ,T2.CNPJ
     ,T2.NUMERO_AGENCIA
     ,T2.NUMERO_CONTA
     ,T2.QUANTIDADE_ITENS
     ,T2.VALOR_ITEM
     ,T2.VALOR_TRANSACAO
     ,T2.STATUS_TRANSACAO
     ,T2.DATA_INI_CONTABILIZACAO
     ,T2.DATA_FIM_CONTABILIZACAO
     ,T2.DATA_INI_RETROATIVO
     ,T2.DATA_FIM_RETROATIVO
     ,T2.ATIVO
     ,T2.DATA_INSERT
     ,T2.DATA_UPDATE
     ,T2.APP_INSERT
     ,T2.APP_UPDATE
     ,T2.VALOR_PEDIDO_EC  
from   dbo.TB_FATURA_ITEM_TRANSACAO_HST   T2
```

I was wondering using Schemabiding on View , but I was looking in some articles that is not recommended when you are using UNION .

Probably I got see which indexes I will use on it, right ?

..................................................................

I applied the query that Gordon posted, I got huge performance on it. I reduced 15 minutes to 5 minutes. Anyway I got hustle on it to reduce more time.

Comment: Are the tables feeding into the view properly partitioned and indexed? The best way to optimize this is going to be optimizing the tables that feed the view. How fast do select statements currently run against the view as compared to the tables alone? Besides that, how often do you need to look at historical transactions?

Comment: @Skeik , yeah , all those tables are partitioned . But the second one hasnt index on it . So i need to look at it all the time .

Comment: Adding an index to TB_FATURA_ITEM_TRANSACAO_HST will probably help. It's not the easiest answer but I think your best bet is going to be avoiding using the view as often as possible.

I've had to work with a similar view before, with 500m+ transactions. In the business logic we determined if the query required history data and only then did we use the view. If it's necessary on a regular basis we cached the data. I can't think of too many reasons that people need to search through 100m~ raw transactions ad-hoc regularly.

Comment: @Skeik i understood what u saying . I'll do some tests and as soon as possible i will post it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overhead in the view is due to duplication elimination.  So, the first suggestion is to use `union all`, if there are no duplicates between the two tables.  If you can, problem solved.

If not, you can use `not exists`.  I might speculate that something like this would work:

```
select . . .
from dbo.TB_FATURA_ITEM_TRANSACAO  T1
union all
select . . .
from dbo.TB_FATURA_ITEM_TRANSACAO_HST Th
where not exists (select 1
                  from dbo.TB_FATURA_ITEM_TRANSACAO T1
                  where t1.id = t2.id 
                 );
```

This `where` clause in the subquery would contain all columns that need to be equal for a row to be considered a duplicate.  I am speculating the `id` is sufficient.

Comment: acttually i've to use view on this solution . Futhermore i gonna use that query above on procedure that I working on it.

Comment: @Luiz . . . And?  You can use `union all` in a view.